# Does the probability of rolling a specific 3 digit number [including permutation] with 3 dice change if that specific number has a double or triple?

Tags: probability, permutations, dice

Is there a difference in probability when rolling a specific number with 3 dice [with permutation] of the specific number digits are unique, doubles or triples?

In other words is the probability of rolling the specific number 1-2-3 [including permutations of 3-1-2, et al] with 3 dice the same as the probability of rolling the specific number 1-1-1?

If the probability is different than what would the probability of rolling the specific number 1-2-2, a specific number with a double instead of a triple?

Comment: There are six ways to get $\{1,2,3\}$.  There is only one way to get $\{1,1,1\}$

Comment: Thank you for the simple, obvious response. I was overthinking this.